# Java - strings equals when decompiled

Tags: java, string, optimization, equality, string-interning

I decompiled some Java code the other day and found this:

```
String s1 = "something";
String s2 = "something_else";

if (s1 == s2) {
// Path 1
} else {
// Path 2
}
```

Obviously using '==' to test for string equality is bad

But I wondered - This code has been compiled and decompiled. **If all the strings have been defined at compile time and interned and the code has been compiled - is it possible that s1.equals(s2) could have been optimized down to 's1 == s2'?**

Comment: One way would be compiling a code just like that, and seeing what comes back from the decompiler :)

Comment: What compiled code was it decompiled from?

Comment: Assuming you use the same version of the compiler that they used to create the original class file.

Comment: This looks like an "optimization" that the programmer would have performed (correctly or incorrectly), not that the compiler would have performed.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? [String#equals](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java?av=f#1013) is using `==` as first test already.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was wondering if any of the compilers would do this: For example as well as the oracle/sun compiler there is openJDK, jRocket etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly doubt it. As a rule, Java compilers do very little by way of bytecode optimization, leaving optimization to the JIT phase.

I've experimented with this a little, and my compiler doesn't do anything interesting with the following:

```
public class Clazz {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String s1 = "something";
        final String s2 = "something_else";
        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }

}
```

This would probably be the easiest case to optimize. However, the bytecodes are:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #16                 // String something
       2: astore_1      
       3: ldc           #18                 // String something_else
       5: astore_2      
       6: ldc           #16                 // String something
       8: ldc           #18                 // String something_else
      10: invokevirtual #20                 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      13: ifeq          27
      16: getstatic     #26                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      19: ldc           #32                 // String yes
      21: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      24: goto          35
      27: getstatic     #26                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      30: ldc           #40                 // String no
      32: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      35: return
```

I therefore strongly suspect the `==` was part of the original source code.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not look like Java optimizes this away (by default).

I just benchmarked both solutions. If it is unoptimized, we expect to see `s1.equals(s2)` slower than `s1 == s2`. This is exactly what we see. If it were optimized, then `s1.equals(s2)` would take the same amount of time as `s1==s2`. However, they take different amounts of time (on the order of 50,000 nanoseconds). This is *not* a direct measurement of this compilation, but it is a reasonable inference.

The reason this will not be optimized to `==` is because the equals operator, for objects, will compare the object memory address, not the contents of the object itself. So, if you change `s1`, then, if the compiler optimized this, you would also be changing `s2`.

However, that risks breaking code, so the compiler won't do that. It will leave the memory addresses of `s1` and `s2` be.

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp I think it was tactical. Oh well.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that the JIT doesn't optimize this. Did you write a sensible benchmark with warmup, own method, etc. etc.?

Comment: @Voo To be honest, it was more quick and dirty. Average of a few hundred thousand System.nanoTime(). However, it's fairly accurate that way anyway. And, I'm not surprised it isn't optimized (see my answer).

Comment: @Telthien Your explanation doesn't make sense I fear, since strings are immutable. So as long as we have `s1 = "Foo"` and no later assignment to s1 in *this* method, the compiler can be sure he knows the startaddress of the char buffer.

Comment: @Voo See the above answer: It's not optimized.

Comment: @Telthien The above answer answers it for java *bytecode*, not actual JIT generated code.

Comment: @Voo Hmm. I'm not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

The main rule is that if the compiler could deduct exact value from the source code it has in the single class. Because it does all optimizations using only smallest compilation unit - class.
If I write a code

```
public class Test
{
    private static final String i = "1";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if(i == "2")
            System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println("world");
    }
}
```

The compiler sees all code related to the statement in this class and optimizes out the if condition. After de-compiler the code looks like

```
public class Test
{
  private static final String i = "1";

  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    System.out.println("world");
  }
}
```

(I've used [jd-gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui))

However, if you replace `==` by the `.equals`, compiler cannot assume how the method `.equals` works. Because, after compilation of the `Test` class, you could hack your JDK and place another version of the `java.lang.String` class which returns `true` for `"1".equals("2")`.

So, thinking about optimization which compiler could do, first of all think how compiler could behave if any class could be recompiled later.

As another example, you could see [how `enum` is implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873725/decompiling-java-with-jad-limitations/7874115) and why does it need such "weird" way.